# How can we access hyphen included data from the JSON response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, vue-component

I am using vuejs and axios, I am trying to get blog posts from wordpress, everything working fine except one thing, I am trying to extract the thumbnail from the response, but the response data contains hyphen so I am not able to access the object, showing error. Here is what I am trying to access

```
family._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.family-profile-thumb.source_url
```

here `family` is a prop, and family-profile-thumb is the specific size, I could not change that, this part creating problem, if i replace this with default sizes like thumb it will work, eg:

```
family._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url
```

Is there a way to get this work?

Comment: `.["family-profile-thumb"].`

Comment: As I said I am using Vuejs, so in template I am using like this <img :src="family._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url" alt=""> If I replace thumbnail and add as you provided wont work,even if I change double quote to single quote, right?

Comment: You can check this gist https://gist.github.com/hygull/df535d30cdd20afc2a6e17aaa292494b too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it using square bracket notation:

```
family._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"]["0"].media_details.sizes["family-profile-thumb"].source_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever property name is not a valid JS identifier you need to use `[]` bracket notation to access the property.

> What are valid JS identifier ?

- property name should not start with `digit` e.g -> `1d`
- Anything other other than `alphanumeric, underscore and $` is not valid `e.g -> 'hello-world'`

```js
let a = {
  "hello-world" : 'some value'
}

console.log(a['hello-world'])
console.log(a.hello-world)
```

You can read here for further information [**MDN reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation)